# Converting a JSON object's fields into Title Case

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

I have a JSON object I get from a database (using Slim and Twig) but there's a field that is sometimes in upper case, sometimes in lower case, sometimes in camelCase, etc. I'd like that this field becomes TitleCase.

I already have a function to convert a String to TitleCase, which I have used when converting JSON to arrays (using these arrays as sources for jqWidgets) :

```
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
}
```

Now I'd like to do the same thing for JSON objects. What I thought of is to iterate over them after using parseJSON(), use my function on the fields I want and return new objects after using JSON.stringify(); but I'm wondering if you think this is the best approach to this problem or if you have a better idea (I'm not asking for direct source code).

Example of my JSON (I need nomFonction and nomEntite in TitleCase) :

```
"[{"idFonction":"1","nomFonction":"Manager","nomEntite":"DIRECTION"},{"idFonction":"2","nomFonction":"Développeur","nomEntite":"SERVICE CONTROLE"},{"idFonction":"3","nomFonction":"Stagiaire","nomEntite":"SERVICE COMPTABILITE"},{"idFonction":"4","nomFonction":"rjeizjrze","nomEntite":"DIRECTION"}]"
```

Comment: Do you want both into one field called TitleCase or two separate ones? Like `{"TitleCase" : "Manager Direction"}` or `{"nomFonction: "Manager", "nomEntite":"Direction"}`? Sorry, I don't fully understand the end result :)

Comment: The latter, both into their original fields.

Comment: Well seeing as this is an opinion-based question (and some SO crusaders might ignore you for it), IMO you could just parse the JSON and iterate over it like `for(var i = 0; i < myArray.len; i++) { // change props }`. Which is probably the way you were doing it and I don't see any real problem with it.

Comment: Yeah that's the way I considered doing it and that's the way I'm making it if you believe it's the correct (and perhaps the best) way to do it. I just wanted confirmation, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I did what I wanted to do which is iterating over the JSON object converted to an Array and convert it back to JSON.

**Code :**

```
// Converts a string to TitleCase
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
}

/**
* @jsonArray : the array to convert
* <...> :  the fields to convert in the JSON
*/
function JSONToTitleCase(jsonArray /**/) {
    s = $.parseJSON(jsonArray); // Array from the JSON
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); // the fields to convert

    // for each JSON object
    for (i=0; i < s.length; i++){

        // for each field to convert to TitleCase
        for (j = 0; j < args.length; j++){

            // if the field exists
            if (typeof s[i][args[j]] != "undefined"){

                // convert it
                s[i][args[j]] = toTitleCase(s[i][args[j]]);
            }
        }
    }
    // back to JSON
    return JSON.stringify(s);
}
```

**Usage :**

```
JSONToTitleCase(JSON_Array, fieldtoconvert1, fieldtoconvert2, ...);
```

*In my case :*

```
JSONToTitleCase(fonctionsEnBase, "nomEntite", "nomFonction");
```